# A person who doesn't waste goods

Tags: single-word-requests

Like someone went to the hotel and doesn't want to waste any freebies so he takes it up with himself to home

Comment: The answer to your title might be "thrifty", but I'm not sure about the body of your question. If you take stuff from the hotel, that's technically stealing, not being thrifty.

Comment: Depends what he does with the items. If they were left where they were, they would not be 'wasted' but used by other people. We don't have sufficient context to know exactly what you are documenting.

Comment: Also, the slang term for free items is "freebies" not "free bees"

Answer (score 0):

Most hotels assume you will take the freebies with you:

> freebies:  the shampoos, soaps, lotions.
>   not freebies: sheets, robes,
>    pictures on the wall, and the TV.

a **thrifty** person

> [thrifty](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/thrifty): showing thrift; economical or frugal
>   <sub>Collins Dictionary</sub>

Comment: The Telegraph: [What can you get away with stealing from hotels?](https://www.telegraph.co.uk/travel/travel-truths/What-can-you-get-away-with-stealing-from-hotels/)

Comment: @James It can be good fun stealing from the hotel to watch the dawn.  It depends where the hotel is.